# Setting the data after switch change in Intl tel input in angular (Bind the data)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input in angular and used it as described by timdoes in the third comment at https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/issues/589.

I am currently having a structure like -

profile.component.html

```
<div [ngSwitch]="activeSection">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'case1'">

    <form class="form" #userForm="ngForm">
      //form elements
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" #intlInput
                                                   [appIntlTelInput]="intlOptions"
                                                   (ngModelChange)="onPhoneInputChange($event)"
                                                   disabled [ngModel]="tempValue" #phone="ngModel">
      //form elements
    </form>
</div
```

profile.component.ts

```
intlOptions = {formatOnDisplay: false, separateDialCode: true, preferredCountries: ['in', 'us']};
tempValue: any;
@ViewChild('intlInput') intlInput: ElementRef;
            onPhoneInputChange(value: string) {
                    this.tempValue = value;
                }
ngOnInit() {
    (jQuery(this.intlInput.nativeElement).intlTelInput('setNumber', '+91*********'));
}
```

The problem I am facing right now is that I am able to set the value on init but when the switch case is changed the jquery code shows the error something like - cannot find nativeElement of undefined and the ngmodel also does not work.

Any idea how to make it retain the data after switch also?